# What does " Add randomness: count=383 entropy=381" mean?

Tags: android, debugging, logcat, android-logcat, android-debug

Just fount this on Android Studio Logcat.
I was just curious what this is.

**Add randomness: count=383 entropy=381**

Comment: This question has inspired some [interesting Wikipedia-ing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing) "Entropy") on my part.